# Passing Variable value to _IENavigate Autoit

Tags: autoit

I have an array called `$urls` which holds URLs. I want to use `_IENavigate` in a `For`-loop to visit each of those URLs, but don't know how to use an array with `_IENavigate`.

This is what I have so far:

```
If Not _FileReadToArray("\urls.txt", $urls) Then
    MsgBox(4096, "Error", " Error reading log to Array. Error:" & @error)
    Exit
EndIf

For $u = 1 to $urls[0]
    _IENavigate($mIE, $urls)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

To access array element number `N` you use `$aArray[N]`.

```
Local $aArray[6] = [5, "Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar", "Goodbye"]

For $i = 1 To $aArray[0]
    ConsoleWrite(  $aArray[$i]   & @LF)
Next
```

So in your above example, you want to use `$urls[$u]` within the For...Next loop.

Answer (score 1):

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611562/matt) is [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17543263/959484). He's actually adapting your code structure and providing a working example.

As long as you don't have to deal with the indexes of the Array inside of your loop, it's cleaner not to use the size of the array in the first element and then use a `For ... In ... loop`:

```
For $url In $urls
    _IENavigate($mIE, $urls)
Next
```

To remove the first element, you could `#include <Array.au3>` and use `_ArrayDelete($urls, 0)`. But I'd rather read in the file with the URLs without the size stored as the first element:

```
$urls = StringSplit(StringStripCR(FileRead("urls.txt")), @LF, 2)
```

- so you don't have to deal with the first element and you are split up by lines already. You can still use `UBound($urls)` to find out about the success.

And just a hint: Use indentation to make your code more readable.